# How to save object field data from controller to salesforce

Tags: visualforce

i am making some changes in the controller and i want to save the updated data to the object in salesforce
how can i do that?

```
 public void getMappingDetails(){


    for(Portfolio_Security_Mapping__c p:getPortfolioMapping(portfolioId))
    {            
        security=getSecurities(p.Security_Id__c).get(0);

        //calculating total_amount for each of the security available in a portfolio
        p.Total_Amount__c=p.Quantity__c*security.Current_Price__c;
        portfolio_amount+=p.Total_Amount__c;
        system.debug(' security beta ' + security.beta__c);
        beta=beta+(security.beta__c*p.Quantity__c);            
        quantity+=p.Quantity__c;

    }

    string searchquery='SELECT Portfolio_Amount__c,Portfolio_Beta__c FROM Portfolio__c where Id=\''+ portfolioId+'\'';
    portfolio=Database.query(searchquery);
    portfolio.get(0).Portfolio_Amount__c=portfolio_amount;
    portfolio_beta=Math.round((beta/quantity)*100.0)/100.0;
    portfolio.get(0).Portfolio_Beta__c=portfolio_beta;
    system.debug(' portfolio beta ' + portfolio_beta);

}
```

i want to save the updated amount details back to the object in salesforce

Comment: didn't you add `update portfolio;` at the end of your method or are you having issues with that?

Comment: i realized what i had to add the same day only
thank you for your help though

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line should do the trick:

```
update portfolio;
```

UPDATE: Just seen highfive's comment. Glad we agree on the potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the data saved. Just added the update statement at the end.
       public void getMappingDetails(){

```
for(Portfolio_Security_Mapping__c p:getPortfolioMapping(portfolioId))
{            
    security=getSecurities(p.Security_Id__c).get(0);

    //calculating total_amount for each of the security available in a portfolio
    p.Total_Amount__c=p.Quantity__c*security.Current_Price__c;
    portfolio_amount+=p.Total_Amount__c;
    system.debug(' security beta ' + security.beta__c);
    beta=beta+(security.beta__c*p.Quantity__c);            
    quantity+=p.Quantity__c;

}

string searchquery='SELECT Portfolio_Amount__c,Portfolio_Beta__c FROM Portfolio__c where Id=\''+ portfolioId+'\'';
portfolio=Database.query(searchquery);
portfolio.get(0).Portfolio_Amount__c=portfolio_amount;
portfolio_beta=Math.round((beta/quantity)*100.0)/100.0;
portfolio.get(0).Portfolio_Beta__c=portfolio_beta;
system.debug(' portfolio beta ' + portfolio_beta);
update portfolio;

}
```